# live browser size detection

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design

This code only works based on the size of the browser at the time of loading, just wondering what could I implement for it get the current browser size and work based on that current information.

I have tried wrapping it in `resize()` but it causes it behave strangely, i.e the toggle goes on and off continuously , or when loading in a shrunk browser it doesnt work at all.

Its a responsive site where the footer menu is just static links on a large screen but turns into drop menu on small screen.

```
    var myWidth = 0, myHeight = 0;

    if( typeof( window.innerWidth ) == 'number' ) {
        //Non-IE
        myWidth = window.innerWidth;
        myHeight = window.innerHeight;
    } else if( document.documentElement && ( document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight ) ) {
        //IE 6+ in 'standards compliant mode'
        myWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
        myHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    }   

    if(myWidth < 980) {
        $("#footer h3").click(function () {
                $(this).toggleClass("active");
                $(this).parent().find("ul").slideToggle('medium');      
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myWidth = 0, myHeight = 0;


function getSize(){

    if( typeof( window.innerWidth ) == 'number' ) {
        //Non-IE
        myWidth = window.innerWidth;
        myHeight = window.innerHeight;
    } else if( document.documentElement && ( document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight ) ) {
        //IE 6+ in 'standards compliant mode'
        myWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
        myHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    }

}

getSize(); // run first time

$(window).resize(function(){
  getSize(); // do it on resize
});


$("#footer h3").click(function () {

        getSize();  // not needed but good to have

        if(myWidth < 980) {
            $(this).toggleClass("active");
            $(this).parent().find("ul").slideToggle('medium');
        }

});
```

Comment: Thanks , this worked well, I ran into another problem where the toggle is staying even when I go back to large screen size, but I think I can fix that myself.

Answer (score 1):

You should use css media queries instead:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 980px) {
   // css goes here...   
}
```

OR include conditional style sheets:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="small-device.css" />
```

[Here is a great article disusing responsive design](http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design)

Comment: And... will this work in IE8? Millions of people still really love that browser

Comment: you'll need to use something like http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/ to make IE8 play nice

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var waitForFinalEvent = (function () {
    var timers = {};
    return function (callback, ms, uniqueId) {
        if (!uniqueId) uniqueId = "Don't call this twice";
        if (timers[uniqueId]) clearTimeout (timers[uniqueId]);
        timers[uniqueId] = setTimeout(callback, ms);
    };
})();

$(window).resize(function(){
    waitForFinalEvent(function(){
        // put all your code here 
    }, 20, "resize"); // replace 20 with every milliseconds to execute during
                      // resize
})
```

The code you put in there will execute every time the window resizes, simply using `resize()` won't always work because it doesn't necessarily check as you're resizing.